# Downloading all files and folders from S3 bucket to local folder in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js, s3-bucket

I need to download all files and folders from an s3 bucket to a local folder in sam hierarchy.

Suppose my s3 bucket basepath is: **myBucket/user1/**

in which and **user1** may have dynamic values. Every folder for users contains 3 sub folders **image, audio, video** and files in them.

i just want to download all files in folder **user1** to local file system in paths

```
/assets/s3files/user1/<FILES & FOLDERS HERE>
```

i have tried: **skipper-better-s3**, but it reads one the file we have passed.

```
adapter = require('skipper-better-s3')({
      key: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      secret: 'yyyyyyyyyyy',
      bucket: 'myBucket'
    });

adapter.read('/assets/s3files/user1/image/file1.jpg', (err, data) => {
    // data is now a Buffer containing the avatar 
});
```

Comment: Did you find the solution??